# C# DateTime to long conversion off by one second

Tags: c#, datetime

I found a conversion of DateTime to long, and vice versa. Upon testing the conversions, I found that they sometimes give results that are off by one second from the original time. 
Here is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

```
public static class DateTimeConstants
{
    public static readonly DateTime ZeroTime = 
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
}

public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static long ToLong(this DateTime value)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt64((value.ToUniversalTime() - 
            ZeroTime).TotalSeconds)
    }
}

public static class LongExtensions
{
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this long value)
    {
        var dateTime = ZeroTime.AddSeconds(value);
            return dateTime.ToLocalTime();
    }
}

public void ConvertDateTimeToLongAndBackTest()
{
    var initialDateTime = DateTime.Now;

    var longDateTime = initialDateTime.ToLong();

    var result = longDateTime.ToDateTime();

    Assert.AreEqual(result.Date, initialDateTime.Date);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Hour, initialDateTime.Hour);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Minute, initialDateTime.Minute);

    // Fails on the following line sometimes
    Assert.AreEqual(result.Second, initialDateTime.Second);
}
```

Sometimes the resulting DateTime is the same as the original DateTime I instantiated for the test, but sometimes it is off by one second. Why is this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - until we can reproduce this, there's not a lot we can do. Well, other than to point out that your `Convert.ToInt64` code will be truncating to a whole number of seconds...

Comment: Why would you convert the result to a long? It seems precise when staying with double.

Comment: @MaorVeitsman do you have any other way of passing unix time over the internet to a Swift application?

Comment: _passing unix time over the internet to a Swift application?_ - That's the question you should have asked.  Typical [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, since you're truncating the number of seconds, it's quite obvious that you can lose up to a second of precision. E.g. `12.8 seconds` might print out as `13` with rounding, but your algorithm turns it into `12`. Even with rounding you can get into trouble, if you don't use the same rounding consistently.

**EDIT:** Now that you've actually added your code, I can be more specific - `DateTime.Second` truncates the current second, while `Convert.ToInt64` rounds it. So for 12.8 seconds, you'll get second 13 instead of the original 12. The fix is simple - replace the convert with a simple cast. Or, if you can't change the format (that is, someone already relies on the faulty behaviour), change the test to round seconds up in the datetime.

If you want unix time, use unix time. If you want a binary format for persistence, use `ToBinary`. Don't try to make your own datetime format, dates are anything but simple.

Comment: I simply inherited this untested code, and decided to test it; what about this code truncates the seconds? Your answer doesn't seem specific enough.

Comment: @Dagrooms I already started as soon as you edited your question with a complete example :)

Comment: I thought my original post provided enough information - didn't think I needed to show the filler code, but I've made it copy/pasteable for anyone

Comment: @Dagrooms Well, in general, if you have a discrepancy between two views of the same data, at the very least you should show us how both of the views are constructed - you only gave code for one, leaving us guessing for the second one. As far as the first view is concerned, the two datetimes are identical - if you run both through the same view, you get the same result.

Comment: @Dagrooms And just for completeness-sake, note that the internal data of the DateTime structure is actually a `long`, so you can avoid the floating point calculations just by using `Ticks` instead of `TotalSeconds`. This is safe, since one tick is 100ns by contract (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx).

Comment: @Dagrooms And since you really want unix time, using the cast is the correct option - the seconds are supposed to be truncated, not rounded. Oh, and of course, `DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTime` (and `FromUnixTime`).

Comment: Basically, if you have _more_ than 500 milliseconds in your `DateTime`, `TotalSeconds` will yield an extra second. [Example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NGZr47)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` has precision down to small fractions of a second. It is likely that the `TotalSeconds` function is rounding either up or down each time it is called. That would account for the discrepancy that you are sometimes seeing when converting the number back.

Whenever the number is rounded up, it will add one second to the result.